# SwingWorker done method throws cancellationexception with get()

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swingworker

I faced an issue of creating  stop/start jbuttons for my gui, and after a LOT of googling, i realized i needed multi-threading. Upon further reading i discovered the swingworker class, and i managed to get my GUI to respond to the STOP button.

now my problem is this

The doinbackground() method executes a piece of code that captures packets in an infinite while loop with the condition (!isCancelled), and once it is cancelled (The STOP button executes worker.cancel()) it returns an ArrayList of packets which theoretically, i should be able to obtain inside the done() method using get(). right? But when i try to do this i get a CancellationException and this is driving me nuts right now.

any help would be highly appreaciated!
Thank you

edit: obj is an ArrayList declared outside of the class to store the return values.

here is my code executed by the START jbutton

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {


    final ArrayList packet_list = new ArrayList();
    obj.clear();

    try {
        worker = new SwingWorker<ArrayList,Integer>(){//initialze swingworker class


            @Override
            protected void done(){

                try {  

                    obj = get();

                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

            //opens up stuff required to capture the packets    
            NetworkInterface   [] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
            int index = (jComboBox5.getSelectedIndex()-1);
            JpcapCaptor captor =JpcapCaptor.openDevice(devices[4], 65535, false, 20); 

            @Override
            protected ArrayList doInBackground(){  

                while(!isCancelled()){

                    try {
                        Packet packets = captor.getPacket(); //captures packets

                        if (packets != null)  //filters out null packets
                        {

                            //System.out.println(packets);
                            packet_list.add(packets); //adds each packet to ArrayList
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(100);

                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        return packet_list;
                    }
                }
                return packet_list;

            }


        };

        worker.execute();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                 


The stop button simply executes 

worker.cancel(); no errors there. and this is the swingworker declaration

 private SwingWorker<ArrayList,Integer> worker;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cancel` doesn't just set the `isCancelled` flag for you to read at your leisure. That would be pretty much useless. *It prevents the task from starting if it hasn't already and may actively interrupt the thread if it's already running.* As such, getting a `CancellationException` is the *natural consequence* of cancelling a running task.

To further the point, the Javadoc on `isCancelled` states:

> Returns true if this task was cancelled before it completed normally.

Hence if this returns `true`, *then your task cannot complete normally*. You cannot cancel a task and expect it to continue as per normal.

`SwingWorker` docs say "An abstract class to perform lengthy GUI-interaction tasks in a background thread". However, the definition of "lengthly" is different for GUI and for an application lifetime. A 100ms task is very long for a GUI, and is best done by a `SwingWorker`. A 10 minute task is too long for a `SwingWorker` simply because it has a limited thread pool, that you may exhaust. Judging by your problem description, you have exactly that - a potentially very long running task. As such, you should rather *make a proper background thread* than use a `SwingWorker`.

In that thread, you would have either an `AtomicBoolean` or simply a `volatile boolean` flag that you can manually set from the EDT. The thread can then post an event to the EDT with the result.

Code:

```
class PacketCaptureWorker implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean cancelled = false;
    public void cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (!cancelled) {
            //do work
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Use the result of your computation on the EDT
            }
        });
    }
}

new Thread(new PacketCaptureWorker()).start();
```

Comment: thank you for the really fast response! and the code. so i should forget swingworker for this specific task. I hardly know anything about threads so first i should probably read up on that.  il follow up if i run into difficulties thx again

Comment: just wondering, can't I use a volatile boolean to test the condition inside the while loop for the swingworker method?

Comment: @user269952 Yes, you *could* do that, I believe it would get rid of your immediate problem. The problem with long-running tasks in a SwingWorker is that there can only be 2 running in parallel (in the current implementation). Hence if you start 2, any other ones will have to wait. You seem to have only 1 at the moment, this is more of a "Can become a problem further down the road if you add functionality"

Comment: ah i see. i decided to go with a separate thread like you suggested. I used an extended Thread class and put the invokeLater method inside a separate function. Its pretty smooth thx a ton for ur input. Learnt a lot too! cheers

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a volatile boolean instead of using worker.cancel() for the swingworker thread while loop and it works beautifully. (atleast on surface) I managed to create a normal background thread as well  and that too worked liked a charm :D Many thanks you saved me a major headache! Wondering what the best method is out of the two.

A follow up, i had to make the volatile boolean available for the whole class, because i had to create 2 seperate instances for the thread class, one to use the START and the other to use the STOP. Apparently two different instances does not address the same instance of the variable. is this bad practice?

Comment: New questions should be posted as actual questions, not as answers. 2 instances will share a variable only if they have a reference to said variable, or if the variable is static. Variables are not shared between object instances by default.

Comment: apologies! I will remember that. thank you for the clarification.